# Числа, которые могут быть представлены в типе float

Tags: c, float, ieee-754

Пусть дано 32-битное число unsigned int. Как определить, можно ли его представить во float? 
C числами размером до 23 бит я разобрался: они полностью влезают в мантиссу размером 23 бита. Но некоторые числа больше 23 бит тоже могут быть представлены точно. Как это определить?

Comment: `i == (unsigned int)(float)i`

Comment: @PetSerAl: Заманчиво, но не могут ли ошибки при конверсиях взаимно скомпенсироваться?

Comment: @VladD Зависит от того, какой результат вернёт `(unsigned int)f`, если `f` равно `2^32`. В остальных случаях преобразование к `unsigned int` не должно имееть ошибки.

Comment: `(i / (i ^ (i & (i - 1)))) < (1 << 23)` @VladD Вот без перехода к `float`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ответ обнаружился в [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limits_on_integer_values):

- Положительные числа до 2²⁴ включительно представляются точно
- Положительные числа от 2²⁴ + 1 до 2²⁵ округляются до кратного 2
- Положительные числа от 2²⁵ + 1 до 2²⁶ округляются до кратного 4
- ...
- Положительные числа от 2¹²⁶ + 1 до 2¹²⁶ округляются до кратного 2¹⁰³
- Положительные числа от 2¹²⁷ + 1 до 2¹²⁸ − 2¹⁰⁴ округляются до кратного 2¹²⁷⁻²³
- Положительные числа от 2¹²⁸ превращаются в бесконечность.

Аналогично для отрицательных чисел.

---

Округление производится в сторону ближайшего кратного. Для равноудалённых случаев используется «банковское» округление: 2²⁴ + 1 округляется вниз, 2²⁴ + 3 вверх, 2²⁴ + 5 снова вниз и т. д.

---

По поводу недостающего отрезка от 2¹²⁸ − 2¹⁰⁴ до 2¹²⁸ − 1: в моём эксперименте числа от 2¹²⁸ − 2¹⁰⁴ до 2¹²⁸ − 2¹⁰³ − 1 при превращении в `float` давали результат 2¹²⁸ − 2¹⁰⁴ (то есть, округлялись вниз до кратного 2¹²⁷⁻²³), а большие округлялись вверх (то есть до бесконечности).

Я не знаю, гарантировано ли это поведение стандартом IEEE 754, но это поведение кажется логичным, так как оно совпадает с поведением для меньших чисел.

Comment: *Положительные числа от `2^128` превращаются в бесконечность.* Не должно ли здесь быть `2^128 - 2^104 + 1`, а то непонятно, что происходит с числами в интервале от `2^128 - 2^104 + 1` до `2^128 - 1`?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Я скопировал текст из википедии, сейчас как раз проверяю, что происходит с остальными числами.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Написал дополнение ответа.